# How to label discrete line in a parallel matrix in plotly.express.parallel_coordinates

Tags: python, plotly, parallel-coordinates

I want to add to mark each line with professor number. In the colorbar legend, I want to show each professor with specific color line legend. How to do that?
currently, I am using this:

```
fig = px.parallel_coordinates(data, color='Professor',title="Parallel Mattrix of Evaluation Data from DataWeierstrass.csv")
```

[image: Professor Evaluation]

Comment: there's an open issue about this with pllotly. they more or less say they aren't going to support it. https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1968

Comment: @Roy2012 Good to know but I want to remind that *plotly.js* is an open source package. One of the four "active" contributors, who is not working at plot.ly anymore, said it's not a priority. One can always create a branch and fix the issue.